# How to make beanplot for only subset of data

Tags: r, plot, subset, data-visualization

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
     stream  n  rates     means   column    value    truevalue
1    Brooks   3   3.0    0.9629152    1    0.42707006 0.9440620
2    Siouxon  3   3.0    0.5831929    1    0.90503736 0.5858527
3    Speelyai 3   3.0    0.6199235    1    0.08554021 0.5839844
4    Brooks   4   7.5    0.9722707    1    1.43338843 0.9440620
5    Siouxon  4   7.5    0.5865031    1    0.50574543 0.5858527
6    Speelyai 4   7.5    0.6118634    1    0.32252396 0.5839844
7    Brooks   5  10.0    0.9637475    1    0.88984211 0.9440620
8    Siouxon  5  10.0    0.5804420    1    0.47501800 0.5858527
9    Speelyai 5  10.0    0.5959238    1    0.15079491 0.5839844
```

And continues on for 56,000 rows. I am trying to make a beanplot and I would like to make 3 different beanplots, one for each stream. I would rather not subset this data frame to create 3 new/ separate data frames. Is there a way to specify that you want a beanplot for `stream=="Brooks"`?

here is what I have

`beanplot(error~rates, data= result, col=c("orange", "black", "white", "red"), border ="pink", what=c(0,1,1,1), maxstripline=.05)`

which works but makes a beanplot for all the data. I tried this which did not work

`beanplot(error~rates, data= result[stream=="Speelyai"], col=c("orange", "black", "white", "red"), border ="pink", what=c(0,1,1,1), maxstripline=.05)`

Comment: I think you just need to add `result$` to your subsetting in the call to data, like `data=result[result$stream=="Speelyai"]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
beanplot(error~rates, data= result[result$stream=="Speelyai", ], col=c("orange", "black", "white", "red"), border ="pink", what=c(0,1,1,1), maxstripline=.05)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think like this:

```
beanplot(error~rates, data= result[result[,"stream"]=="Speelyai",], col=c("orange", "black", "white", "red"), border ="pink", what=c(0,1,1,1), maxstripline=.05)
```

Or, if you wanted something more compact, try using `data.table`. More compact in terms of the subsetting, once you get it set up (you can do it w/o setting key first and it'll still be more compact, but a bit slower):

```
# load package
library(data.table)

# convert to data.table, and set key for subsetting
result <- as.data.table(result)
setkey(result, stream)

# save your original plotting code (minus the data part) as an expression
original.plot <- expression(beanplot(error~rates, col=c("orange", "black", "white", "red"), border ="pink", what=c(0,1,1,1), maxstripline=.05))

# make the plot for this stream only
result["Speelyai", eval(original.plot)]
```

Then, if you want to make the plot for those 3 streams, you could do something like

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2)) # I'm doing 4 panels just so it's a square; 1 will be empty
result[c("Brooks","Siouxon","Speelyai"), eval(original.plot), by=c("stream")]
```

It can take a little while to get used to data.table, but it tends to be very convenient notation and very fast. Very handy for subsetting, or performing a task for multiple subsets.

Comment: @Christopher Note that `data.table` makes it easy to extend the approach to making the plot for each stream. You can do the first way in a `for()` loop, if you want.